# Access Any Apps Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

Is it possible to take action when a notification of any app is received by the iOS device? For example, when a WhatsApp notification is received, can we take action in some way?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this (unless you are doing a jailbreak app then maybe ).

For security reasons Apple will not allow applications to communicate with each others.

Apps are in some sort of sandbox where they can only use some user informations (with permission of course) and other system ressources.